# What is the link between hydrogen production and potassium oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, hydrogen

Is there an industrial process that produces hydrogen with potassium oxide as a catalyst?

Or is there a process for the production of potassium oxide that has hydrogen as a by-product?

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia page of potassium oxide states:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_oxide)

> Potassium hydroxide cannot be further dehydrated to the oxide but it
> can react with molten potassium to produce it, **releasing hydrogen as a
> byproduct.**
>
> $$\ce{2KOH + 2K <=> 2K2O + H2 ^}$$

Comment: Would you have a mixed alkali metal oxide if the following takes place: $$\ce{2Na + 2KOH ->[\Delta] 2NaOK + H2}$$

Comment: @Kav [Maybe](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24641/does-naoh-react-with-k-to-form-naok-or-koh)